# Bounding continuous function from range and value at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset (-2,-1) \cup [1,5)$
2. $f(0)=e$

Can you give realistic bounds for $f$ ?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for tips on how to type maths

Comment: $f(\mathbb{R})\subseteq[1,5),$ since $e\in[1,5)$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $f(0) = e$, you know $f$ has values in $[1,5)$. It's not hard to construct a function that will use them all.

However, since the values in $(-1,1)$ are **not** in the range of $f$, can $f$ have values in $(-2,-1)$ if is continuous? (Think about intermediate value theorem.)

Comment: Pls explain it more thoroughly

Comment: If $f$ be continuous then $f(a)<0<f(b)$ implies that \there exists c\in $R$ such that $f(c)=0$. But here $(-1,1)$ \notin $R$.  Thus $f$ is not continuous.  Now if $f$ be continuous then the realistic bound for $f$ should be $[1,5)$, because otherwise $f(0)=e$ will contradicts the fact about continuity. Am I right, Sir ?

Comment: @gobindachandra exactly